# Understanding -regex with GNU find

Tags: find, regular-expression, xargs

### Background

I have what I think *should* be a simple case.  I want to find all files with "cisco" in the name and do something with those files (via [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)).

#### Finding files with `ls`

Before I use [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs), the first step is listing all relevant files.  Listing files is easy with `ls | grep cisco`...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort post]$ ls | grep cisco
cisco-asa-double-nat.rst
cisco-asa-packet-capture.rst
cisco-eem-tcl.rst
cisco-ip-sla-tracking.rst
cisco_autonomous_to_lwap.rst
[mpenning@Bucksnort post]$
```

#### Finding files with `find`

Although it's probably not required in this specific case, [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is generally considered safer when piping into [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).  However, all logic seems to go out the window when I use `find -regex`.

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort post]$ find -regextype grep -regex ".*/cisco*" -print
[mpenning@Bucksnort post]$
```

However, I know I can [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) those files...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort post]$ find | grep cisco
./cisco-eem-tcl.rst
./parsing-cisco-output-w-textfsm.rst
./cisco_autonomous_to_lwap.rst
./cisco-ip-sla-tracking.rst
./cisco-asa-double-nat.rst
./cisco-asa-packet-capture.rst
[mpenning@Bucksnort post]$
```

### Questions

I realize that `find -regex` has to match the full path that is returned, but why isn't `find -regextype grep -regex ".*/cisco*" -print` working above?  Shouldn't `.*/cisco*` match the path?

---

*NOTES*

I know I could just use `find -path "*cisco*"` to solve the problem, but the point of the question is to understand why my `-regex` usage is wrong.

Comment: Because the representation of `./` means "from the dir i´m in, to deeper", and it should not have a `*` between those characters. `-regex "./*cisco*" ` should match the path, but not `-regex ".*/cisco*" `; EDIT: There is a simmilar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111067/regex-match-either-string-in-linux-find-command :)

Comment: You probably want: `.*/cisco.*`.

Comment: As Herman and otokan have pointed out, the problem is you are using `*` wrongly at the end.  It means something different in a regular expression than a glob.  However, if you use it *unquoted* with `grep` (e.g. `ls | grep cisco*`), **it passes through the shell first and is treated as a glob, not a regexp.**  This behavior has maybe led you to believe the wrong thing.

Comment: @goldilocks, after more than a decade of regex usage, you'd think I'd know that by now.  Old shell globbing habits die hard :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Finding with `ls`**: first things first, `ls | grep cisco` is a bit verbose, since `cisco` isn't a regular expression. Try:

```bsh
ls *cisco*
```

**Using `find`**: along the same lines, `-regex` is overkill with a simple, static pattern. How about:

```
find -name '*cisco*'
```

The quotes are required so the glob is interpreted by `find`, not the shell. Also, `-print` is required for many versions of `find`, but is optional (and the default predicate) for others (e.g. GNU `find`). Feel free to add it if you need it.

If you need to search for ‘cisco’ in the full pathname, you could try this:

```
find -path '*cisco*'
```

which is equivalent to `find | fgrep cisco`.

**Using `find` with regular expressions**: let's do that anyway, since this is what you want. Shamelessly copying from the GNU `find` manpage:

> -regex pattern
>
> ```
>           File  name  matches  regular  expression  pattern.  This is a match
>           on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file named
>           `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or `.*b.*3',
>           but not `f.*r3'.
> ```

What this means is that your regular expression is wrapped in an invisible `^...$`, so it must match *every* character in the full pathname of the file. So, as nwildner and otokan said in the comments, you should use something like:

```
find -regex '.*cisco.*'
```

And you don't even need the `-regextype` for something this simple.

Comment: About your first sentence. I hate to be pedantic, but `cisco` *is* a regular expression also, which matches the string `cisco`. It's just not a very fancy regex.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `find -regex ".*/cisco*"` won't match any paths like `./cisco-eem-tcl.rst` or `./cisco_autonomous_to_lwap.rst` is as follows:

- `.*` matches anything - any character, zero or more times
- `/` matches a single slash - so far so good
- `cisco*` matches `cisc`, followed by any number of `o`'s.

Remember that the asterix `*` operator constrains the  repetition of its preceding item which is `o` in this case. That means we have nothing matching this last component of the pattern, because it would be something like `cisc`, `cisco`, `ciscoo`, `ciscooo` ... ad infinitum.

If you need to express that anything can follow the word `cisco`, then use `.*` after that:

```
find -regex '.*/cisco.*'
```

Maybe you'd like to be a little more restrictive on your search results by matching only `rst` files:

```
find -regex '.*/cisco.*\.rst'
```

However, doing a simple match on the filename component of the path such as this doesn't require the expressive power of regexes so you can do just fine using only `-name` with a [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) to get the same match:

```
find -name 'cisco*.rst'
```

and to process these matches with `xargs` you would do somthing like this:

```
find -name 'cisco*.rst' -print0 | xargs -0 command
```

You should always remember that regexes and globs are different things syntactically and semantically. See `man find` and read about the `-name` and `-regex` options to learn more.